# What is the historical-linguistic origin of the high variety of the Burmese language?

Tags: historical-linguistics, sociolinguistics, sino-tibetan, register, diglossia

In Myanmar (Burma), a state of diglossia exists.

How did the high (formal) variety originate historically? Did it use to have native speakers at some point in the historical development of the Burmese language?

Is any of the modern spoken varieties of the Burmese language a direct descendant of the formal variety?